# Simple JMS Example Does Not Retrieve JMS Message. Why?

Tags: java, jms

Please help.  This is killing me for two weeks.

I just want a simple standalone java client that sends a JMS message to a JMS Queue on a glassfish server running on localhost.  AND receives it back.  I just can't seem to make this work.  Code is below.  Followed by Console output I get when I run it from the Eclipse workbench.

The message gets sent without an error. (see last line in Console)  But the listener never retrieves it.  Can anyone help.  It really would be a nice example for the next person who tries to lean JMS -- if it ever worked.  Can anyone offer help?

[Note: I use a ton of print statements to produce the console output below, but I removed them from the code for readability.  And I emptied the glassfish server log before running it. After running it, the log added no lines.]

Code:

```
public class JMSTest implements MessageListener {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JMSTest messageCenter = new JMSTest ();
    messageCenter.sendMessage();
  }

  static final Properties JNDI_PROPERTIES = new Properties() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      {this.put ("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
       this.put ("java.naming.provider.url","file:///C:/glassfish4/mq/opt/java/my_broker");
      }
  };

  String            QUEUE_NAME          = "jms/JMSSendToTestQueue";
  MessageConsumer   msgConsumer         = null;
  MessageProducer   msgProducer         = null;
  ObjectMessage     msg                 = null;
  Connection        connection          = null;

  //constructor
  public JMSTest () {
    try {
/*1*/ Context jndiContext = (Context) new InitialContext(JNDI_PROPERTIES);
/*2*/ ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/goConnectionFactory");
/*3*/ connection = factory.createConnection();
/*4*/ Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
/*5*/ Destination receiveFromDestination = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup(QUEUE_NAME);
/*6*/ this.msgConsumer = session.createConsumer(receiveFromDestination);
/*7*/ this.msgConsumer.setMessageListener(this);
/*8*/ Destination sendToDestination = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup(QUEUE_NAME);
/*9*/ msgProducer = session.createProducer(sendToDestination);
/*10*/this.msg = session.createObjectMessage();
      this.msg.setObject("Hi There. I'm a Test Object.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("    " + iAmM + "msg: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void sendMessage() {
    try {
      this.msgProducer.send(this.msg);
      System.out.println("Message Was Sent");
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      System.out.println("Attempt to send message failed.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    System.out.println("TEST MESSAGE RECEIVED");
    if(this.connection!=null) {
      try {
        this.connection.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    try {
      ObjectMessage objMsg = (ObjectMessage) msg;
      System.out.println((String) objMsg.getObject());
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Console:

```
JMSTest.<init> ()                  beg
    Line 1: InitialContext ok: 
            javax.naming.InitialContext@3b9a45b3

    Line 2: factory is not null: 
      Sun Java System MQ ConnectionFactory
      Class:            com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory
      getVERSION():     3.0
      isReadonly():     true
      getProperties():  
        imqOverrideJMSPriority              = false
        imqConsumerFlowLimit                = 1000
        imqOverrideJMSExpiration            = false
        imqAddressListIterations            = 1
        imqLoadMaxToServerSession           = true
        imqConnectionType                   = TCP
        imqPingInterval                     = 30
        imqSetJMSXUserID                    = false
        imqConfiguredClientID               = 
        imqSSLProviderClassname             = com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
        imqJMSDeliveryMode                  = PERSISTENT
        imqConnectionFlowLimit              = 1000
        imqConnectionURL                    = http://localhost/imq/tunnel
        imqBrokerServiceName                = 
        imqJMSPriority                      = 4
        imqBrokerHostName                   = localhost
        imqJMSExpiration                    = 0
        imqAckOnProduce                     = 
        imqEnableSharedClientID             = false
        imqAckTimeout                       = 0
        imqAckOnAcknowledge                 = 
        imqConsumerFlowThreshold            = 50
        imqDefaultPassword                  = guest
        imqQueueBrowserMaxMessagesPerRetrieve = 1000
        imqDefaultUsername                  = guest
        imqReconnectEnabled                 = false
        imqConnectionFlowCount              = 100
        imqAddressListBehavior              = PRIORITY
        imqReconnectAttempts                = 0
        imqSetJMSXAppID                     = false
        imqConnectionHandler                = com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.protocol.tcp.TCPStreamHandler
        imqSetJMSXRcvTimestamp              = false
        imqBrokerServicePort                = 0
        imqDisableSetClientID               = false
        imqSetJMSXConsumerTXID              = false
        imqOverrideJMSDeliveryMode          = false
        imqBrokerHostPort                   = 7676
        imqQueueBrowserRetrieveTimeout      = 60000
        imqSetJMSXProducerTXID              = false
        imqSSLIsHostTrusted                 = false
        imqConnectionFlowLimitEnabled       = false
        imqReconnectInterval                = 3000
        imqAddressList                      = 
        imqOverrideJMSHeadersToTemporaryDestinations=false}

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line 3: connection is not null:
      BrokerAddress=localhost:7676(60325)
      ConnectionID=967799204788496640
      ReconnectEnabled: false
      IsConnectedToHABroker: false

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line 4: session is not null: 
        ConnectionID                        = 967799204788496640
        SessionID                           = 967799204788508160

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line 5: receiveFromDestination not null:
      Sun Java System MQ Destination
      getName():        JMSSendToTestQueue
      Class:            com.sun.messaging.Queue
      getVERSION():     3.0
      isReadonly():     false
      getProperties():  
        imqDestinationName                  = JMSSendToTestQueue
        imqDestinationDescription           = A Description for the Destination Object}

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line : msgConsumer not null:
        ConnectionID                        = 967799204788496640
        SessionID                           = 967799204788508160
        ConsumerID                          = 967799204788511232
        DestName                            = JMSSendToTestQueue

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line 7: listener set to this:

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line 8: sendToDestination not null:
      Sun Java System MQ Destination
      getName():        JMSSendToTestQueue
      Class:            com.sun.messaging.Queue
      getVERSION():     3.0
      isReadonly():     false
      getProperties():  
        imqDestinationName                  = JMSSendToTestQueue
        imqDestinationDescription           = A Description for the Destination Object}

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line : msgProducer not null:
        ConnectionID                        = 967799204788496640
        SessionID                           = 967799204788508160
        ProducerID                          = 967799204788513792
        DestName                            = JMSSendToTestQueue

    JMSTest.<init> ()                  Line 10: ObjectMessage created.
                                                Object is String: Hi There. I'm a Test Object.
Message Was Sent
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call start() on your connection in order for a MessageConsumer to have message start being dispatched.  You can send messages without starting the connection but you cannot receive anything until it has been started.

Comment: Thank you. Obviously right.  Obviously embarrassing. But in the meantime I tried updating my glassfish ... and when I tried to reconfigure the Resources it uses (a JDBC Connection Pool - unrelated to this issue) it threw "java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response." that looks like a beast to cure.  But as soon as I get it working again, I'll confirm this works, update the code and click the solved check mark.  Thanks again glb